# Find all pairs $(n,m)$ such that expressions divide.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find all pairs $(n,m)$ where $n$ and $m$ are natural numbers such that $n^3+m^3$ divides $n^2+6mn+m^2.$

We know that $(n+m)(n^2-mn+m^2)$ divides $n^2+6mn+m^2$ and therefore $n+m$ divides $4mn$ and also $n^2-mn+m^2$ divides $7mn$ but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: My first try, which might easily fail, is two-fold: [1] For $~n,m~$ both large enough, $~n^3 + m^3~$ will be larger than $~n^2 + 6mn + m^2.~$ [2] Consider a $\pmod{3}~$ argument.

Comment: @user2661923 Your first approach works well. There are 16-25 cases to manually check (depending on how tightly you do the bound).  $\quad$ Less clear to me how your second approach would work.

Comment: @CalvinLin Assume that neither $~n~$ nor $~m~$ is a multiple of $~3.~$  Then $~n^2 + m^2 \equiv 2\pmod{3}.~$  In this case, you must not have that $~n^3 + m^3 \equiv 0\pmod{3}.~$  This implies (among other things) that $~n \equiv m \pmod{3}.~$  This reduces the cases that need to be manually checked.  I haven't delved too deeply, but I would speculate that something similar happens if you assume that exactly one of $~n,m~$ is a multiple of $~3.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use OP's observation that $n^2 - mn +m^2 \mid 7mn$.
A slightly more natural way to come about it is $n^3 + m^3 \mid 7mn(m+n)$.
Since $mn(m+n) \leq n^3 + m^3 \leq 7 mn (m+n)$, which forces $n^3+m^3 = \frac{7mn(m+n)}{k}$ for some integer $k = 1 $ to 7.

Now, it remains to check which of these could yield integer solutions.
For $k = 1$, we get $ n = -m, (4-\sqrt{15} )m, (4 + \sqrt{15} ) m$, which has no positive integer solutions.
Likewise for $k = 2, 4, 5$ (factor the cubic), we do not get positive integer solutions.
For $k = 3$, we get $n = 3m$ (or $\frac{1}{3} m)$. This gives $28m^3 \mid 28m^2$ or $m = 1$, so $(1, 3), (3,1)$ are solutions.
For $k = 6$, we get $ n = \frac{2}{3}m $ (or $\frac{3}{2} m$). Using $n = 2a, m = 3a$, we get $35a^3 \mid 49a^2$, which has no solutions.
For $k = 7$, we get $n = m$, or that $2m^3 \mid 8m^2$, so $ m \mid 4$. We verify that $(1, 1), (2, 2), (4, 4)$ are all solutions.

---

Notes

1. We could have stuck to OP's terms, and nothing would have changed in this solution. IE $ mn \leq n^2 - mn +m^2 \leq 7mn$.
2. In hindsight, it's easier to check the finitely many cases where $ n^3 + m^3 \leq n^2 + 6mn + m^2$.
   However, this approach can be extended to the negative integers.

Answer (score 1):

You've made a great start. If natural numbers include $0$, then also allowing $0 \mid 0$, we have $m = n = 0$ being a solution. Otherwise, WLOG if $m = 0$ and $n \neq 0$, then $n^3 \mid n^2 \;\to\; n \mid 1 \;\to\; n = 1$. Thus, $(m, n) \in \{(0, 1), (1, 0)\}$ are $2$ more solutions.

With $m$ and $n$ both being positive, then since $n^2 - mn + m^2$ divides $n^2 + 6mn + m^2$, we get $n^2 - mn + m^2$ also divides $(n^2 + 6mn + m^2) - (n^2 - mn + m^2) = 7mn$, as you've already stated. Since $n^2 - mn + m^2 = (n - m)^2 + mn \gt 0$, then there's a positive integer $k$ such that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
k(n^2 - mn + m^2) & = 7mn \\
kn^2 + (-k - 7)mn + km^2 & = 0 \\
k\left(\frac{n}{m}\right)^2 + (-k - 7)\left(\frac{n}{m}\right) + k & = 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

The above is a quadratic equation, with integer coefficients, in the rational $\frac{n}{m}$. Thus, the discriminant must be a perfect square, i.e., for some non-negative integer $d$, we have

$$\Delta = (-k - 7)^2 - 4k^2 = -3k^2 + 14k + 49 = d^2 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

with the results then being

$$\frac{n}{m} = \frac{k + 7 \pm d}{2k} \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

We have $(k, \Delta) \in \{(1, 60), (2, 65), (3, 64), (4, 65), (5, 44), (6, 25), (7, 0)\}$, with all values of $k \gt 7$ causing $\Delta \lt 0$. Thus, only $k = 3, 6, 7$ work, with these giving the results of

$$\frac{n}{m} = 3, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{3}{2}, \frac{2}{3}, 1 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

As expected, due to symmetry, the reciprocal of each potential value is also a value. To check, with $n \ge m$, we have first that $n = 3m$. We then get

$$28m^3 \mid 28m^2 \;\to\; m \mid 1 \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Thus, we have the $2$ solutions of $(m, n) \in \{(3, 1), (1, 3)\}$.

Next, we have $2n = 3m$, so $2 \mid m$ and $3 \mid n$ to get for some positive integer $r$ that $2n = 3m = 6r \;\to\; n = 3r, \; m = 2r$. Thus,

$$35r^3 \mid 49r^2 \;\to\; 35r \mid 49 \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

which has no integer solutions. The remaining possibility of $n = m$ gives

$$2m^3 \mid 8m^2 \;\to\; m \mid 4 \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

Thus, there's the additional solutions of $(m, n) \in \{(1, 1), (2, 2), (4, 4)\}$.

In total, including those where $0$ is allowed, the solutions are $(m, n) \in \{(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 3), (3, 1), (1, 1), (2, 2), (4, 4)\}$.

Comment: I provided a different approach though it ends up with the same equations. That's interesting to me. $\quad$ (Having written it up, I'm still inclined to check the finitely many cases of $n^3 + m^3 \leq n^2 + 6mn + m^2$ compared to the work that's involved.)

Comment: Ah, it's the same because both of our $k$ are the same $7mn/(n^2  - mn + m^2)$. You proceeded to get integer solutions by checking that the discriminant is a perfect square, while I just factored the expressions and discarded the non-integer solutions. That resolves the mystery.